# What do difficulty levels do in Picross 3D: Round 2?

Tags: picross-3d-round-2

In Picross 3D: Round 2 there are difficulty options for Easy, Medium, and Hard. What's the difference between these difficulty options?

[image: Picross 3D Round 2 difficulties]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difficulty levels change what hints you are given on each puzzle and how many points you get for completing each level.

As an example, below is puzzle 16 on each difficulty.

Easy
[image: Easy]

Medium
[image: Medium]

Hard
[image: Hard]